# How to add command line option to ELF binary using cmake and gcc?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have a C++ based application and building the binary for it using `cmake` and `make`. Now, I want to show the version of my binary with something like `--version` flag. In the end I want to achieve `ex_app -v` should show the binary version. In one of the header files I could see a `#define APP_VERSION "1.0"` and this version number is displayed when the binary is executed. Now, I want to display this version number with `-v` command line option. In the existing source files there is no code for "command line options". And I am looking ways to introduce command line arguments for the binary. The binary is of `ELF` format compiled for `GNU/Linux`. I want to know if this is possible to accomplish without majorly modifying source files. Does GCC provide any option to insert version info to ELF binary file?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I understand that this is more of discussion type post and I am looking for some hint to get started.

Comment: Is this really related to the elf format? Is there a requirement that you're able to extract the version with a program extracting info from an elf file? To me this looks like the logic you're looking for is something like `int main(int argc, char*argv[]) { if (argc == 2){std::string_view a1(argv[1]); if (a1 == "-v" || a1 == "--version") { std::cout << APP_VERSION << '\n'; } }}` which wouldn't require you to bother about the location where the info is stored in the binary.

Comment: *"without majorly modifying source files"* -- what constitutes "majorly"? That seems like it's going to be a rather subjective criterion.

Comment: Your goal (*"I want to show the version"*) and your question (*"Does GCC provide any option to insert version info to ELF binary file?"*) are related but not the same. Being able to put information into a binary file does not imply any way for that binary to show the that information. Putting information into a binary can be as simple as finding some unused space (padding) and tossing the info there. It would be in the binary with no way to use it. Showing the information is the harder step, more so if you want to implement a command line argument.

Comment: @JaMiT, Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I agree with your comment. Since the 'version' is already part of binary, I just want to display it with command line option. Because this info will be further used to make some decisions (like to discard older versions of binary). 
"without majorly modifying source files" - I meant with minimal changes to existing source files :-)

Comment: @fabian, thanks for the quick update. Yes, this won't be related specifically to ELF format. I have removed the "elf" tag from OP. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CMake [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) directive to generate a header file with `APP_VERSION` macro.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h.cmake ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.h)
...
```

version.h.cmake:

```
...
#define APP_VERSION "@PROJECT_VERSION@"
...
```

This will take `version.h.cmake` (template) from your source directory, substitute `@PROJECT_VERSION@` with `VERSION` value you set in [`project(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) in CMakeLists.txt and dump it into `version.h` file in build directory.

This is not limited to the project version, you can do this with any CMake variable. For list of CMake defined ones see [cmake-variables(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html).

`version.h` can be then included in your codebase and macro `APP_VERSION` used to display version with `--version` without need of modifying any source files (you just need to bump version in a single central place - `CMakeLists.txt`).

Command line arguments are passed to the program through its `main()` entrypoint as arguments `argc` (count of given arguments) and `argv` (array of C strings representing each argument). First argument is always the command itself. Very naive command line argument processing code example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "version.h"
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        std::string_view a(argv[i]);
        if (a == "-v" || a == "--version") {
            std::cout << APP_VERSION << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "unknown argument: " << a << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For more complicated CLI interfaces (such as some arguments taking a value, value validation, formatting, mutual exclusion etc.) I recommend using some existing library such as [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11).

Comment: *"display version with `--version` without need of modifying any source files"* -- assuming that there is already code in place to process command line arguments... The question mentions *"I want to display this version number with `-v` command line option"* which leads me to believe that the code to do this does not yet exist.

Comment: @JaMiT question is kinda unclear in that aspect. I understood this is in place or OP already knows how to do that but they struggle to get version inside binary without hardcoding it directly in source as their codebase currently does. But honestly just guessing from the mention of "_I could see a #define APP_VERSION "1.0" and this version number is displayed when the binary is executed._".

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, there is no such code to use command line options in existing source files.

Comment: @blami sorry for the confusion. I will update OP to include that "no code for command line option exists in source files". Basically, I am looking to add command line arguments in the source code so that I can use CLI with binary on the target platform.

Comment: @Preeti no worries, I updated my answer with a very naive example to get started.

Comment: @blami while using above solution, I got a error like. `error: 'string_view' is not a member of 'std' 'std::string_view' is only available from C++17 onwards error: 'a' was not declared in this scope`. Since I am doing cross-compilation, can you please let me know how can I fix this without modifying any SDKs?

Comment: @Preeti depending on gcc version you use you might want to add `-std=c++17` which will give you std::string_view (there’s no change in SDK, only using newer standard with existing SDK that enables this feature) or you can construct std::string from argv instead.

Comment: @blami Yes, I found this solution but, I am not sure how to make this permanent instead of passing this to g++/cmake every time. On the other hand , I changed the `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) to set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` in `CMakeLists.txt` and now I am not getting any errors. Please let me know if this is enough.

Comment: @Preeti yes, that is the right way to do it with CMake.

Comment: @blami thanks for the update. What is happening right now is I could display the binary version but doing `ex_app -v` also starts the execution of binary. It is showing version but I don't want it to start binary execution. In the source file in `main.cpp` I have something like `std::cout << "Starting binary " << *** << std::endl;`. Can I make `-v` to only display version without starting it?

Comment: @Preeti Not sure if I understand correctly but if you don’t want to run any other code after printing version then in main just return 0; in the if branch for -v/—version right after printing the version. That will make program stop.

Comment: @blami Yes, adding `return 0` did the trick. Thank you :-)